# Imageresizer Faces Plugin Error

Tags: imageresizer

After installing this both manually and via the package manager I continue to see this error. I was wondering if any of you have encountered this. I get this when I use the ?f.detect=true.

> {"dx":0.0,"dy":0.0,"dw":800.0,"dh":510.0,"ow":800.0,"oh":510.0,"cropx":0.0,"cropy":0.0,"cropw":800.0,"croph":510.0,"features":null,"message":"**Could
>   not load file or assembly 'OpenCvSharp, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6adad1e807fea099' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**"}

Comment: What version of the OpenCvSharp assembly do you have installed? Can you access the diagnostics page /resizer.debug?

Comment: @nathanael-jones, thank you so much for responding.  I have 2.4.10.20170306 of OpenCvSharp-WithoutDll installed. I used nuget for the installation and also tried without nuget and received the same error. Below is an excerpt from my debug file

.OpenCvSharp.Blob        File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)                           
OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus    File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)                            
OpenCvSharp       File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)     
OpenCvSharp.Extensions      File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)                                   
OpenCvSharp.UserInterface        File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)